# extracting domain from host name variable without prefix or suffix with sed

Tags: bash, subdomain, regex-negation

I have been mucking around with this for a couple of hours and cant seem to get it working.
If I have www or ftp.somedomain.net.nz or just somedomain.com and I want to extract just the somedomain from the pattern to set as a variable by echoing the hostname to sed
how would I go about it?

For Example:

```
var="echo $HOSTNAME | sed 's/someregex to fit all$//'"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know the prefixes you can try (either "ftp.", "www." or nothing):

```
var=$(sed -E 's/^((ftp|www)\.)?([^.]*)\..*/\3/' <<< "$HOSTNAME")
```

Using `sed ... <<< $VARIABLE` is preferred to `echo $VARIABLE | sed ...`

Answer (score 6):

Do you really need to use sed?

```
HOSTNAME="${HOSTNAME#*.}"
HOSTNAME="${HOSTNAME%%.*}"
```

Note that this, and some other solutions, won't get along with something like `www.news.google.com` but if you test for things like that you could do:

```
HOSTNAME="${HOSTNAME#*.}"
HOSTNAME="${HOSTNAME#*.}"
HOSTNAME="${HOSTNAME%%.*}"
```

What works depends only how nicely formed your input is.

Answer (score 0):

Double quotes do not run commands. Use backquotes, or better, use `$(...)`:

```
var=`sed 's/[^.]*\.\([^.]*\)\..*/\1/' <<< "$HOSTNAME"`
var=$( sed 's/[^.]*\.\([^.]*\)\..*/\1/' <<< "$HOSTNAME" )
```

You probably have to tweak the regular expression to get the domain. What part of the address do you want? The examples are rather unclear. If you just want to remove www or ftp, you can use Parameter expansion:

```
var=${HOSTNAME#www.}
var=${var#ftp.}
var=${var%%.*}
```

Comment: thanks mate but it is not working, for example it is working on a full www.somedomain.com.au but not on somedomain.com.au